# C# Web Browser content resize

Tags: c#, resize, browser

I've got a C# application, with a WebBrowser inside, the application pulls html links that are believed to be images from a forum and I then tell my WebBrowser to navigate to the image link to display the images one by one.

The problem is that some of these images are a lot larger than the size of my WebBrowser object. I DO NOT WANT TO RESIZE THE WINDOW, I LIKE IT THE SIZE IT IS :)

I want to get the webbrowser page to resize, for example like firefox and chrome do when you open an image link and you dont have them maximized, they just make it smaller to fit the window?

Thanks in advance

SOLUTION: Works a treat, Elerium(Top Answer) provided the link, just changed the VB code to C#

```
double origSizeWidth, origSizeHeight; 
origSizeWidth =webBrowser1.Size.Width; //get the original size of browser 
origSizeHeight = webBrowser1.Size.Height;

HtmlElement pic = webBrowser1.Document.Images[0]; //get your image
double origPicWidth, origPicHeight; 
origPicWidth = double.Parse(pic.GetAttribute("WIDTH")); //save the image width
origPicHeight = double.Parse(pic.GetAttribute("HEIGHT"));//and height

double tempW, tempY, widthScale, heightScale;
double scale = 0;

if(origPicWidth > origSizeWidth){
    widthScale = origSizeWidth / origPicWidth; //find out the scale factor for the width
    heightScale = origSizeHeight / origPicHeight; //scale factor for height

    scale = Math.Min(widthScale,heightScale);//determine which scale to use from the smallest
    tempW = origPicWidth * scale; //multiply picture original width by the scale
    tempY = origPicHeight * scale; // multiply original picture height by the scale
    pic.SetAttribute("WIDTH", tempW.ToString()); // set your attributes
    pic.SetAttribute("HEIGHT", tempY.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like answer you looking for. [Here](http://underwatergoats.blogspot.com/2010/09/automatically-resize-images-in-net.html)

Comment: This outta do it! Nice find